# javax.smartcardio with Java 9 and ClassPath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, smartcard, java-platform-module-system

Under Java 9, various default packages have been switched to Java EE packages (no longer included in JVM - optionally addable).
This is not a problem for most of them because I simply specify the Java EE packages as dependencies. With the said package **javax.smartcardio**, however, I didn't find anything where it could have landed (github-jee, no Maven search result,...). Can someone give me a tip where to get the latest version of the package? Thank you much!

*I have just found out that **javax.smartcardio** still exists as a module **java.smartcardio**. However, this doesn't help me because I am still working with the ClassPath in my project and would have to work with Jigsaw to get it.*

Comment: *I have just found out that javax.smartcardio still exists as a module java.smartcardio* So, what are you asking now?

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean when you say *this doesn't help me because I am still working with the ClassPath in my project* when `module java.smartcardio` is present in the JDK itself?

Comment: I'm working in my application without an moduldescriptor. So I can't use the module 'java.smartcardio'. If I would use a module-info.java I should have to  use the module system in the full application.

Comment: My goal is that I create a JAR with javax.smartcardio included or which automaticly reads the module java.smartcardio(manifest?). So that it runs with Java 9. Again, using module-info seems to be no solution for me.

Comment: I have the same problem, please let me know if you solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `module-info.java` to require the `java.smartcardio` module. This worked for me.

I posted a bit more detailed answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61721513/7287324

Answer (score -1):

I verified that at runtime javax.smartcardio is available out of the box if you are on the classpath.
No --add-modules is required.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem because I was using a project with Java 8 for compile time.

You have to add this to your POM

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>XXXX</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then it compiles ok.