# javax.smartcardio in Java 9, 10, 11, 12... etc

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcardio

What happened to the javax.smartcardio library from Java 9 onwards?
Is there an alternative or some way to obtain it in JAR?

Comment: What do you mean "what happend" - It still exists
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html

Comment: I read that as Smart Cardio and wondered when Java started to have such specific support for things...

Comment: @Kayaman Since 1.6

Comment: @Wufo I meant I read that as Smart Cardio, i.e. workout related functionality. Not Smart Card IO.

Comment: Oh ok. sorry...

Comment: The documentation is often not available in the offline documentation package. You may be tricked because of that that is doesn't exist. I filed [this bug report before](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6549100) but the they decided that devs don't need documentation if it is not part of the Java spec (which is - to me - one of the most idiotic reasoning I've ever heard.

Answer (score 3):

After some hours searching on the web, thanks to the answer above, and as far as I understand, Java 9 and later are modular, which is a language improvement planned some years ago. Also, after the new Oracle rules update, some packages were moved from the SE to the EE version.

The module `smartcardio` is now optional, but it is still included in the SE. So if you want to use it, you have to require it in a `module-info.java`.

Example:

I have created this file in my maven project:
`src/main/java/com/module-info.java`

```
module com.chema.nfc_rfid_reader_writer {
    requires java.smartcardio;
    exports com.chema.nfc_rfid_reader_writer;
}
```

And that's all

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59477660/7287324
https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.smartcardio/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html

Comment: Hi, what if we want to use Maven? should we add "requires" for all dependencies added to maven?

Answer (score 1):

After the java becomes "Modular Development", `javax.smartcardio` has also been modularized.

If you want to use the package after `java 9`, create `module-info.java`.

Please see the image.

[image]

Or you can just degrade the compiler version to `JDK 1.8`:

https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-modularity-jigsaw