# javax.smartcardio on macOS Monterey does not find PCSC readers

Tags: java, macos, pcsc, smartcardio

I want to access a PC/SC Reader (Reiner SCT) on macOS Monterey (12.0.1) using Java 8/11. (`javax.smartcardio` already works in [Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054619/javax-smartcardio-in-java-9-10-11-12-etc/61721513#61721513)). With both Java Version,

```java
TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
```

returns an empty list of readers. I found a similar [issue already for OS X Big Sur](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8255877). Hence I was trying to start my application with the parameter as CLI argument

```sh
-Dsun.security.smartcardio.library="/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/Current/PCSC"
```

but also via the run time code

```java
System.setProperty("sun.security.smadtcardio.library", "/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/Current/PCSC");
```

-- but the list stays empty.

When I list the content of the folder `/System/Library/Frameworks/PCSC.framework/Versions/Current/` on my mac, there is no `PCSC` on macOS Monterey (only `Resources`, `XPCServices` and `_CodeSignature`). Hence I assume there is something missing.

So the question is, what do I need to do, to make `javax.smartcardio` work on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option with `System.setProperty` works for me.

The only problem in my case was, that there was a typo in the property name. The correct property name is `sun.security.smartcardio.library`