Adding GCP Secret Manager SDK to Maven causes "{Type} Not Accessible" Error
Link to Code: https://github.com/phillipshaong/java-gcp-secrets-manager-test/tree/main
I want to add the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Secrets Manager client to my Java application (https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries). I added dependencies to my pom.xml file as instructed:
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
      <version>26.23.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
  </dependency>

And added the module to my module-info.java file:
requires google.cloud.secretmanager;

When I import classes, as instructed:
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.AccessSecretVersionResponse;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.ProjectName;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.Replication;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.Secret;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient; //works
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretPayload;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretVersion;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

Only the import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient; imports successfully, all of the other classes do not, giving me error: The type com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.{Class} is not accessible).
Here is my minimally reproducible code. https://github.com/phillipshaong/java-gcp-secrets-manager-test/tree/main

Why is the question downvoted? Would love some explanation on how to make the question better. Thanks!

Someone said it needs more clarity, but did not bother to leave a comment.., I upvoted it.

have you tried upgrading the maven-compiler-plugin? Currently you're using a version about where module support started. So that's at least a step you should take.

Antoher thing I noticed is that the secretmanager is not modularized (it doesn't have a mdoule-info, nor an Atuomatic-Module entry in the manifest file, so there is a chance it is not going to work. Did you try removing the requirement? that should make it move from modulepath back to classpath, which should make it accessible again.

@RobertScholte, regarding the maven-compiler-plugin, I updated it to be 3.13.0. The intelli-sense still isn't able to resolve the class, but when running mvn compile, it does it without issue. However, when running the command mvn clean compile assembly:single, it produces the error cannot find symbol, symbol: class AccessSecretVersionResponse, location: package com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1 for all the classes other than SecretManagerServiceClient. Debugger also doesn't work.

@RobertScholte, I am also noticing in the .jar files in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF the attribute you're discussing, the Automatic-Module-Name entry. I now know, as you pointed out, that this lets me know that 1) The dependency is Modularized and 2) What the module name is when importing it. I think it is interesting that even though the GCP Secrets Manager doesn't have the Automatic-Module-Name entry, the requires google.cloud.secretmanager, the artifactId, partially loads in the module. Because my application also requires javax.smartcardio, my app must be modularized (link below)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054619/javax-smartcardio-in-java-9-10-11-12-etc/61721513#61721513

Currently, the library google.cloud.secretmanager doesn't support importing though module-info.java. The Cloud Java SDK for Secret Manager doesn't work in a modularized project. The current known workaround is to repackage the JAR files. See thread: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/10975
